# Replace specific range of color in Photoshop with a flat color

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects, photo-editing

I wanted to be able to replace a range of color with a single flat color.

I'm mostly dealing with black and white / grayscale images.

I tried to use the Curve adjustments tool, but the problem is that it doesn't allow you to create straight lines

Here's a random simple example:
[image: Curves]

Here I want to do three things:

1. Replace all colors with values ranging from 0% to 26% with a flat color of 24% value.
2. Replace all colors with values ranging from 26% to 76% with a flat color of 60% value.
3. Replace all colors with values ranging from 76% to 100% with a flat color of 89% value.

And by flat color, I mean no gradients, smooth transitions, just a completely flat even color

And as you can see, the curve tool just does not allow me to create straight lines, making it almost impossible to achieve what I want to do

I tried to use a Gradient Map too, but it doesn't allow me to replace the colors I want with flat colors

Is there any fast and practical way for me to achieve that? Preferably in Photoshop, but if it's necessary to use other softwares, I'm open to that.

**E D I T:**

The type of images I'm working on is grayscaled photographs and realistic paintings

Here is an example of the kind of image I'm working with:

(sorry can't embed, not enough reputation points, see my comment below)

This is what I want to achieve:

[image]

**To clarify, I don't need it to be the edges to be so clean, neat and well-designed. I'm only using this as a fast and speedy visualization tool, and not to create a final product. So speed is important**

Comment: It would help if we could see the actual image you are attempting to edit, or at least a similar image, and perhaps also post an image which shows the kind of result you want.  It's really hard to give advice without seeing it. Also, is the image you are editing a flattened image, or is it a PSD with editable layers?

Comment: I'm not working on a specific image, but I'll add a random example. http://i.imgur.com/KSjQ6hl.png http://i.imgur.com/hCjyGWE.png Generally, the type of picture I'm dealing with is grayscaled photographs and realistic paintings. I'm working with a flattened images. I also clarified my question a bit to make it clearer what I want to achieve

Comment: Is that the result you are looking for, to take a photograph of a painting, and turn it into a posterization effect?

Comment: I want a higher degree of control over the value simplification. Posterization just doesn't allow you to do that. I want to be able to very quickly experiment and shift the value range I want to replace, test out different flat values I'm replacing it with, and just generally fast experimentations with the values

Comment: Have you tried using the Cutout filter?  That's probably your best bet.  I'm not by my own computer at the moment so can't post an example. But it's located in the artistic filters.

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question here before: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95730/how-can-i-recreate-this-posterization-effect/95753#95753 - this is for a colour image, but it should give you an idea of what's possible with the cutout filter

Comment: I've tried both of that, but unfortunately it's just not what I'm looking for. While it's great for quickly graphically simplifying images, it's not the control I want. What I'm really interested is in replacing a range of values with a single flat value I specified, and I just can't control that with those tools.
See this image for example: http://i.imgur.com/e0ynBVQ.png
Values from 0%-20% is replaced with 10%, 30%-60% is replaced with 50% and so on.

Comment: After using the cutout filter you can fill the flat areas of colour with the paint bucket, and specify any colour you want - so it's kind of half way to where you want to go.

Comment: But that won't allow me to control those cutout shapes based on the value range I specified. If there's a way to do that, that'd be closer to what I need

Comment: i can explain it at Ai.... do u want it?

Comment: @DevelopersPedia Yes, please!

Comment: OK, I added an answer that might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Gradient Map](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/applying-special-color-effects-images.html#apple_a_gradient_map_to_an_image) to determine your break points and apply colors accordingly. Since you want it flat you'll just need to put in extra points to make hard stops.

[image]

Adding a Gradient Map, see how there's green at both ends of that color. You can't tell in the screenshot but there's also identical blues and reds at each end of those colors too (you could also remove the ends entirely and then you only have to worry about any colors in the middle):

[image]

Which creates:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! But how do you create hard stops?

Comment: @gnpan just click anywhere on the gradient bar

Comment: @gnpan put 2 stops on top of each other

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method you might find helpful. It uses the Cutout filter as discussed in my comments previously, but in conjunction with a Smart Object and Adjustment layers, which should give you some finer control over the conversion of tones to flat areas in the Cutout, with some nice visual feedback to the adjustments as you are making them.

Proceed as follows:

1. Open an image
2. Add a black and white adjustment layer if the image is not already black and white.
3. Add a Levels adjustment layer
4. Select all the layers in the layers panel, and choose `Filter` > `Convert for Smart Filters`.
5. Apply the Cutout filter.
6. Double click the Smart Object to open it, and arrange both Windows side by side using `Window` > `Arrange` > `2 up Vertical`
7. In the layers panel select the Levels adjustment, and move the sliders.
8. Each time you adjust the levels hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save the Smart Object, and the Cutout filter will update in the other window.

Here's an example of the technique working.

[image: Animation of Using Smart Object to make adjustments]

Another nice thing about this is that the Cutout Filter is applied non-destructively to the Smart Object, which means you can go in and adjust the number of colour levels, and other sliders in the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Take freeware. Image editor Paint.NET has plugin Curves+ which allows also piecewise linear curves.

Curves+ is a part of Pyrochild plugin package which also is freeware.

[image]

NOTE: Paint.NET and its plugins are available from numerous download sites. I recommend to avoid other than the original site https://www.getpaint.net/ because malware pushers use popular freeware to get people hooked.