# How do I create this pixel effect look in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixel-art

I want to recreate this pixel effect on an image in Photoshop. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: This was most probably created by hand. Not everything is an effect.

Comment: Looks like ASCII art, could have easily been code.

Answer (score 1):

It's a kind of posterization effect, where the different graylevels are created with line-grids (brighter > thicker lines).

The crucial part is to find a photo with good contrasts and shadows, that will look good after posterization (eg 3-4 levels in grayscale). A flat lighting will not produce good results.

In PS you can test posterization via `Image > Adjustments > Posterize`. If the results looks good, you can redraw the different gray-level zones with the line grids. In your example the artist has very likely added some extra level of styling eg. to the hair.

A similar posterization procedure can be found in this [GDSE thread](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95730/how-can-i-recreate-this-posterization-effect).

Comment: Hi AAGD. Can I draw your attention to [this discussion](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/what-to-do-with-tutorial-requests-part-ii) on meta? We are trying to decrease the amount of lazy 'tutorial-on-demand' questions on the site, and one of the early signs is that answering them isn't a good idea. I'd appreciate your input on the matter. Thanks!